# Eu não sei mais como dar o deploy do rocket chat no heroku. Ajuda?

Tags: git, github, deploy, heroku

1 - Eu não consigo dar upgrade no npm. 
Acontece esse error:  Your configured registry (https://registry.npmjs.org/) may not support audit requests, or the audit endpoint may be temporarily unavailable.
Já tentei npm install / npm audit fix / npm audit e sempre caio nos mesmos erros!

2 - Slug.
 !     Compiled slug size: 515.6M is too large (max is 500M).
 !     See: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-size
Já coloquei um slugignore mas parece que não adiantou.

3 - A versão do meu node é v10.15.2
e do npm é 6.14.4

4 - Seguindo a documentação (https://rocket.chat/docs/installation/paas-deployments/heroku/) onde devo dar o comando: git remote add heroku https://git.heroku.com/portalidea.git // vem o erro: fatal: remote heroku already exists.

5 - e por fim quando dou **git push heroku master**, eu recebo o erro: 
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/portalidea.git'

Alguém poderia me dar uma luz?

Comment: Os detalhes estão aqui :(   https://pastebin.com/nhNRzLpw

Answer (score 0):

Uma causa raiz clássica para esta ultima mensagem é:

> quando o repo foi inicializado, mas
>   nenhuma confirmação foi feita

Se você não adicionou e se comprometeu pelo menos uma vez, não haverá uma master filial local para a qual enviar.

Tente `git commit -m "first commit"`e tente `git push -u origin master`novamente.

Consulte [Por que preciso enviar explicitamente uma nova ramificação?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096311/why-do-i-need-to-explicitly-push-a-new-branch/17096880#17096880) Para obter mais informações.